# Rank and hyperbolic volume

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a hyperbolic $3$-manifold whose fundamental group has rank $r.$ What is the best (lower) bound on the volume of $M?$ Similar question for rank of $H_1.$ There is a bunch of papers of Culler and Shalen on related subjects, but they seem to care about "small" manifolds, whereas this question is more on the asymptotic dependence.

Comment: Is there an opposite inequality, i.e. a bound on the volume in terms of the rank (minimal number of generators)? I am a total novice in this field so perhaps I am unaware of some canonical counterexample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [Counting arithmetic lattices and surfaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2482), Mikhail Belolipetsky, Tsachik Gelander, Alex Lubotzky and Aner Shalev prove the following Theorem.

> Let $H$ be a connected simple Lie group of real rank one. Then there is an effective computable constant $C=C(H)$ such that for any lattice $\Gamma < H$ we have $r(\Gamma)\le C\cdot \mathrm{vol}(\Gamma\backslash H)$, where $r(\Gamma)$ is the minimal number of generators of $\Gamma$.

Applying this to $SO(1,3)$ gives $\mathrm{vol}(M) \ge 1/C\cdot r(\pi_1(M))$ in your case.

Comment: I interpreted "rank" as "minimal number of generators", I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks! This is obviously sharp (in terms of growth rate) in dimension $2,$ but less obviously so in dimension $3...$

Comment: The growth rate is sharp in dimension 3 as well. For example, take cyclic covers over one component of the Whitehead link complement. The rank (of $H_1$) and the volume both grow linearly.

Comment: Note that on 2204 of the published paper, a fairly explicit estimate is given in terms of the Margulis constant. The Margulis constant is estimated in a paper of Meyerhoff. However, when the rank of $H_1$ is at least $3$, one may assume the Margulis constant is $\geq \log(3)/2$. So this should give an improvement in this case.

Comment: @IanAgol Ah, OK. I will need to ponder what this means in the grand scheme of things...

Comment: @IgorRivin: By the way, the Margulis constant $\log(3)/2$ is asympotically optimal, in the sense that manifolds with constant smaller than this will be of bounded volume, and therefore of bounded rank. So for large enough rank, one may use the better formula giving a lower bound on volume. But I still wouldn't expect this constant to be close to optimal.